# Tag header, filha da tag section, herda valores de outra tag header

Tags: html, css

Tenho essa estrutura HTML:

```
<body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <div class="limit">
        <section class="conteudo">
            <header>
                <h1>TESTE</h1>
                <h3></h3>
            </header>
            <article>
            </article>
        </section>
        <section class="comentarios">
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
```

E essa folha de estilos CSS:

```
/* header principal - topo da pagina */
header{
    background:#FE634A;
    border-bottom:2px solid #D24726;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}

section.conteudo{
    width:960px;
    height:200px;
}

/* tag header da section.conteudo - titulo do artigo*/
section.conteudo header{
    width:960px;
    height:200px;
}
```

---

O que acontece?

O seletor 'section.conteudo header' herda os atributos 'header' que é algo que eu não aconteça, o que faço para impedir isso? Alguma solução elegante para que não aconteça isso?

No caso o meu site ta ficando assim:

[image: site]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma solução seria dar uma classe ao primeiro `header`:

```
<body>
    <header class="header-principal">
    </header>

.header-principal {
    ...
}
```

Outra seria usar o seletor de filho para que a primeira regra só se aplique aos `header`s diretamente abaixo do `body`:

```
body > header {
    ...
}
```

Por fim, você pode "desfazer" no `header` interno o que você fez no externo (resetando as propriedades para seu valor *default*):

```
section.conteudo header{
    background:transparent;
    border-bottom: medium none inherit; /* Acho que é esse o default */
    width:960px;
    height:200px;
}
```

Comment: sabe? eu não achei tão elegante ter que usar o 'body > header' para fazer isso, será que alguma outra solução para isso? Ou esse é o melhor?

Comment: @heromax Pessoalmente, eu iria com as classes. Mas não tenho nenhuma razão, objetiva ou não, para escolher entre uma e outra... Exceto que, com classes, você pode estilizar elementos diferentes da mesma forma, se quiser.

Comment: Talvez sim, eu altere, mas vou usar isso que vc respondeu, obrigado pela ajuda! :) Marquei como resolvido! Agora sim a pagina está da maneira que eu queria. vlw ae.

Answer (score 0):

Coloque um atributo de filho

```
section.conteudo>header
{

}
```

Comment: eu coloquei do jeito que vc pediu, não funcionou mas eu tentei 'body>header' e deu certo, então vlw ai pela dica.Mas será que tem uma solução mais "elegante", porque não achei legal usar 'body>header' para estilizar o <header> principal (O topo da pagina)

Comment: @heromax Você vê algum problema específico de se usar `body > header`? A menos que você esteja preocupado de, no futuro, mudar a estrutura da página e esquecer de alterar a regra, não vejo problema algum em se usar o seletor de filho...

Comment: talvez sim, eu altere, mas vou usar isso que vc respondeu, obrigado pela ajuda! :)